# Set NSSearchfield with NSArrayController bindings programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsarraycontroller, nssearchfield

I have added a `NSSearchField` on top of a `NSTableView` programmatically. I would like to populate the TableView with an existing `NSMutableArray` which is having values in it (not nil). I would like to add everything programmatically in my program and bind `NSArrayController` to the array and in turn populate the TableView.

The place where I'm stuck is, I have to bind this `NSMutableArray` to `NSArrayController` and when I search in the search bar, the change has to effect in the TableView.

My TableView is a single column TableView, I'm missing the link of bindings some where.

I would like to know how a pre-populated `NSMutableArray` is bound to `NSArrayController` which is in turn bound to `NSTableView`?

Comment: I'm checking at Interface Builder and NSSearchField height is fixed at 22px. Can you try adding with 22px height at your frame size?

Comment: Also, I've tested your code on my project and search field is being displayed. You should update your question with more code...